# Solaris 11 change IP in zone

Tags: ip, solaris, zones

I've changed the IP on the global zone. Now I want to change the non-global zones.

I login with zlogin  and use 
`ipadm delete-addr net0/?`

There is a ? behind net0/
So I can't delete and set new.

Is there another way to change the IP of this zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the global zone, you might check the output of:

```
$ dladm | grep <zone-name>
$ dladm show-linkprop <zone-name>/<iface>
zonename/aggr0 allowed-ips rw 10.2.42.142 10.2.42.142 --  --
```

Then, you should be able to change it using:

```
$ dladm set-linkprop -p allowed-ips=10.x.y.z zonename/aggr0
```

This might do the trick, I know if you have the link-protection to allow only listed IP address, this will update the list without the need for a reboot.

NOTE: I don't have a test zone available to actually verify this, but I know I already did this once in the past and it actually worked...